# Is there a way to make a form that always begins with https://?

Tags: html, css, forms, placeholder

I have a form set up that changes when the value is inputted in settings. The issue is that when someone enters google.com instead of https://google.com, the link doesn't work. I'm wondering if there is any way to have the form always display https:// and the user then inputs their link after.

I want the https:// included in their inputted link, not to go away like with a placeholder. Is there anyway to get this done?

Here is my code for the specific form.

```
                    type="text"
                    value={logoLink}
                    placeholder="https://yourwebsitehere.com"
                    onChange={(event) => setLogoLink(event.target.value)}
                  />
                  <Button type="submit">Save</Button>
```

Comment: Hi, can you show the full code so I can help you

Answer (score 0):

You could remove any text up to and including a "://" and prepend "https://", like:

```
let s = "google.com";
const re = /^.*://///;
let u = new URL("https://" + s.replace(re, ""));
console.log(u.href);
```

Outputs:

```
https://google.com/
```

and it outputs the same with `let s = "http://google.com";`.

---

Or maybe [`<input type="url">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url) would work for you to force the user to add the protocol.